# How to map a class that contains a list of objects of various type to a collection of tables with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

I have a class that is called `Element` and it is subclassed by `User` and `Entity` that have some common fields like value, id and uuid and some others that are not common..

```
@Entity
class Element {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String uuid;
    private String value;
}

@javax.persistence.Entity
class Entity extends Element {
   private String description;
}

@Entity
class User extends Element {
   private String password;
}
```

I also have a class Information:

```
@Entity
class Information {
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;
   private List<Element> elements;
   private String information_field1;
   private String information_field2;
}
```

elements can contain `Users` and `Entities`

How would you suggest I should map that with Hibernate..

I was thinking that in the database I could have those tables

```
Element
----------------
information_id, user_id, entity_id, order 
0, null, 10, 0
0, 12, null, 1

Information
----------------
id, information_field1, information_field2
0, "some value", "some other value"
```

That represents `Information` with id 0, having first (order = 0) `Element` being an `Entity` with id 10 and second (order = 1) `Element` being a `User` with id 12.

I don't mind a completely different db design as long as it doesn't lose information but the class structure isn't possible to be changed. I know how to make it work with classes that are exactly the same as the rows of the tables I suggested. I am curious if Hibernate annotations are sophisticated enough so when I store `Information` it will insert the appropriate rows, ids and order in the two tables.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what worked for me

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Element {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "element_id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "uuid", nullable = false)
    private String uuid;
    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;

    public Element(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Element() {

    }

    @PrePersist
    public void initUuid() {
        this.uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

---

```
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="element_id")
public class Entity extends Element {
    private String description;


    public Entity() {
        super();
    }

    public Entity(String value, String description) {
        super(value);
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

---

```
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="element_id")
public class User extends Element {

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public User(String value) {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

---

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
public class Information {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "information_id")
    private Long id;
    private String uuid;
    private String value;
    private String innerText;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH} )
    private List<Element> elements;

    public Information() {

    }

    public Information(String innerText, List<Element> elements) {
        this.innerText = innerText;
        this.elements = elements;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getInnerText() {
        return innerText;
    }

    public void setInnerText(String innerText) {
        this.innerText = innerText;
    }

    public List<Element> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }

    public void setElements(List<Element> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }
}
```

I then extend the CrudRepository interfaces:

```
public interface InformationDao extends CrudRepository<Information,Long> {
    List<Information> findAll();
}

public interface ElementDao  extends CrudRepository<Element, Long> {
    List<Element> findAll();
    Element findByValue(String value);
    Element findById(Long id);
}
```

And for testing purposes I have this Service.

```
public class InformationService {

    @Autowired
    ElementDao elementDao;
    @Autowired
    InformationDao infoDao;

    @Transactional
    public void init() {
        List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>();
        Element element1 = new Entity("test", "description");
        Element element2 = new User("test2");
        Element element3 = new Entity("test3", "description");
        Element element4 = new User("test4");

        elements.add(element1);
        elements.add(element2);
        elements.add(element3);
        elements.add(element4);

        elementDao.save(elements);

        Information info = new Information("some text", elements);
        infoDao.save(info);

        List<Element> elements2 = new ArrayList<>();

        Element element5 = elementDao.findById(element1.getId());
        Element element6 = elementDao.findById(element2.getId());
        Element element7 = elementDao.findById(element3.getId());
        Element element8 = elementDao.findById(element4.getId());
        elements2.add(element5);
        elements2.add(element6);
        elements2.add(element7);
        elements2.add(element8);
        elementDao.save(elements2);
        Information info2 = new Information("@ something else @", elements2);

        //failTransaction();
        infoDao.save(info2);
    }


    public void failTransaction() {
        throw new RuntimeException("transaction failed");
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that due to

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH} )
private List<Element> elements;
```

on `Information`, all `Elements` need to be already pre-stored in the database. I couldn't make it to work with `CascadeType.ALL` that stores children Element all the time when the parent element is stored. I was getting `detached entity passed to persist` when I was trying to store `info2`

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate documentation https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-mapping explains how to map collections. You must use `@OneToMany` and `@JoinTable` annotations.

```
@Entity
class Information {
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany
   @JoinTable(
        name="INFORMATION_ELEMENTS",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="INFORMATION_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="ELEMENT_ID")
   )
   private List<Element> elements;
   private String information_field1;
   private String information_field2;
}
```

This will create a table INFORMATION_ELEMENTS that contains the Information to Element mappings. You don't need to maintain INFORMATION_ID in the Element table.

Comment: I know how to do it in the way you described.. Elements can be used in many Information objects so I guess it will become many to many... plus what will happen with Users and Entities that are subclasses of Elements? Also how about the order that I need it to be stored? Those are the parts that made me ask the question

Comment: As long as User and Entity belong to the same table, it should not cause any problem. I am not sure though

Comment: yeah but they won't be the same table since they are two different objects - I found how to do it and I will post shortly